# Hover popups with a bit more complicated behaviour

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, information-display

Well, it is not the biggest deal actually, but it would be a little bit nicer if popups will support two modes of the way they actually popup. Here is a picture to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

Comment: That would be nice.  How would you do it?  Is there a jQuery plugin that supports that kind of behavior?

Comment: @Robert, I don't know about exactly plugin, but core jQuery functionality makes this task approachable. Yet, it's not trivial as one can expect it to be. We need is to compute offset of the element which triggers hover event and to measure current viewport. The trickiest is - to compute the height of the popup container. I mean, it is also relatively easy, but there are subtle issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good idea - tags will now pop up from the bottom if they are just outside of the window height after render.  Look for this on our next deploy.